# How can I get an Liferay Asset Entry's friendly URL to its Display Page?

Tags: freemarker, liferay-7.3

I've created a Blog Display Page Template, and marked it as default. Now, from inside a Fragment that has a BlogEntry object, a want to get its Display Page friendly URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getFriendlyURL` method from `AssetDisplayPageFriendlyURLProvider`

```
[#assign
  assetDisplayPageFriendlyURLProvider = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.asset.display.page.portlet.AssetDisplayPageFriendlyURLProvider")
  friendlyURL = assetDisplayPageFriendlyURLProvider.getFriendlyURL(assetEntry.getClassName(), assetEntry.getClassPK(), themeDisplay)
/]
${friendlyURL }
```